# How to embed HTML into IPython output?

Tags: python, html, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to embed rendered HTML output into IPython output?

One way is to use

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML('<a href="http://example.com">link</a>')
```

or (IPython multiline cell alias)

```
%%html
<a href="http://example.com">link</a>
```

Which return a formatted link, but

1. This link doesn't open a browser with the webpage itself from *the console*. IPython notebooks support honest rendering, though.
2. I'm unaware of how to render `HTML()` object within, say, a list or `pandas` printed table. You can do `df.to_html()`, but without making links inside cells.
3. This output isn't interactive in the PyCharm Python console (because it's not QT).

How can I overcome these shortcomings and make IPython output a bit more interactive?

Comment: Is this what you want to do? http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/integrating.html

Comment: @cel It formats html output just like `HTML()` does, but I still couldn't solve items 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm not an expert, so this could be wrong, but I feel that injecting arbitrary html code into the representation of other objects won't work. This would couple logic and representation of an object and is probably not desirable. But you sure could write wrapper objects, that contain the original object and use the _repr_html_ method to provide a custom html representation.

Comment: Actually, I just ran your code and it worked as soon as a moved on to a different cell...

Comment: Adding JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852885/ipython-adding-javascript-scripts-to-ipython-notebook/47414836#47414836

Answer (score 371):

This seems to work for me:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'))
```

The trick is to wrap it in `display` as well.

Source: http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Printing-HTML-within-IPython-Notebook-IPython-specific-prettyprint-tp5016624p5016631.html

Edit:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
```

In order to avoid:

> ```
> DeprecationWarning: Importing display from IPython.core.display is 
> deprecated since IPython 7.14, please import from IPython display
> ```

Comment: Can this version exeucte javascirpt?

Comment: Here is a link to an example notebook showing the display possibilities: [Rich Output](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Rich%20Output.ipynb)

Comment: The _display_ part allowed me to embed JavaScript in a notebook

Comment: Is this a feasible method for producing a website if I need to make it with Dash and all my python code is in Jupyter .ipynb file?

Comment: What I meant is if I need to make a website containing a dashboard made from Dash and Flask and all my code is in jupyter .ipynb files, can I just use a seperate html and css files in Atom to do that part and link it to the code in Jupyter files or does all my code need to be in .Ipynb file. Would appreciate any help on this point as I'm new to this.

Comment: Consider adding `target="_blank"` in links in notebooks (except in Markdown cells to other `.ipynb` files).

Comment: Any ideas for a `display` alternative that works with Voila?

Comment: This "Rich Output" notebook link works: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/main/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Rich%20Output.ipynb

Comment: I got a deprecation warning.  The new import statement us `from IPython.display import display, HTML`.

Answer (score 60):

Some time ago Jupyter Notebooks started stripping JavaScript from HTML content [[#3118](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3118)]. Here are two solutions:

**Serving Local HTML**

If you want to embed an HTML page with JavaScript on your page now, the easiest thing to do is to save your HTML file to the directory with your notebook and then load the HTML as follows:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame

IFrame(src='./nice.html', width=700, height=600)
```

---

**Serving Remote HTML**

If you prefer a hosted solution, you can upload your HTML page to an Amazon Web Services "bucket" in S3, [change the settings on that bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html) so as to make the bucket host a static website, then use an Iframe component in your notebook:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame

IFrame(src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/visualizations/isolation-forests.html', width=700, height=600)
```

This will render your HTML content and JavaScript in an iframe, just like you can on any other web page:

```html
<iframe src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/visualizations/isolation-forests.html', width=700, height=600></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was looking for. I use this to render plotly charts interactively in my static blog site

Comment: Wouldn't a local file be easier than throwing something on AWS?

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I needed - because I want to host an entire web application on a Jupyter Notebook from Amazon SageMaker. Thanks!

Comment: For extra marks, run an interactive web server asynchronously from a cell and interact with the pages it creates inside an iFrame in other cells!

Comment: @holdenweb you just found a secret level

Comment: @holdenweb can you give a code example for how to do this?  This sounds like a very cool idea.

Comment: Simple proof of concept at https://gist.github.com/holdenweb/fb8de56e33cdfaef9218673915cc7f1c

Answer (score 25):

Related: While constructing a class, `def _repr_html_(self): ...` can be used to create a custom HTML representation of its instances:

```
class Foo:
    def _repr_html_(self):
        return "Hello <b>World</b>!"

o = Foo()
o
```

will render as:

> Hello **World**!

For more info refer to [IPython's docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#rich-display).

An advanced example:

```
from html import escape # Python 3 only :-)

class Todo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add(self, text, completed):
        self.items.append({'text': text, 'completed': completed})

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return "<ol>{}</ol>".format("".join("<li>{} {}</li>".format(
            "☑" if item['completed'] else "☐",
            escape(item['text'])
        ) for item in self.items))

my_todo = Todo()
my_todo.add("Buy milk", False)
my_todo.add("Do homework", False)
my_todo.add("Play video games", True)

my_todo
```

Will render:

> 1. ☐ Buy milk
> 2. ☐ Do homework
> 3. ☑ Play video games

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on @Harmon above, looks like you can combine the `display` and `print` statements together ... if you need. Or, maybe it's easier to just format your entire HTML as one string and then use display. Either way, nice feature.

```
display(HTML('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'))
print("Here's a link:")
display(HTML("<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>www.google.com</a>"))
print("some more printed text ...")
display(HTML('<p>Paragraph text here ...</p>'))
```

Outputs something like this:

---

### Hello, world!

Here's a link:

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

some more printed text ...

Paragraph text here ...

---

Answer (score 4):

First, the code:

```
from random import choices

def random_name(length=6):
    return "".join(choices("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", k=length))
# ---

from IPython.display import IFrame, display, HTML
import tempfile
from os import unlink

def display_html_to_frame(html, width=600, height=600):
    name = f"temp_{random_name()}.html"
    with open(name, "w") as f:
        print(html, file=f)
    display(IFrame(name, width, height), metadata=dict(isolated=True))
    # unlink(name)
    
def display_html_inline(html):
    display(HTML(html, metadata=dict(isolated=True)))

h="<html><b>Hello</b></html>"    
display_html_to_iframe(h)
display_html_inline(h)
```

Some quick notes:

- You can generally just use inline HTML for simple items.  If you are rendering a framework, like a large JavaScript visualization framework, you may need to use an IFrame.  Its hard enough for Jupyter to run in a browser without random HTML embedded.
- The strange parameter, `metadata=dict(isolated=True)` does not isolate the result in an IFrame, as [older documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/nbformat.html) suggests.  It appears to prevent `clear-fix` from resetting everything.  The flag is no longer documented:  I just found using it allowed certain `display: grid` styles to correctly render.
- This `IFrame` solution writes to a temporary file.  You could use a data uri as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6102829/1320510) but it makes debugging your output difficult.  The Jupyter `IFrame` function does not take a `data` or `srcdoc` attribute.
- The `tempfile`
  module creations are not sharable to another process, hence the `random_name()`.
- If you use the HTML class with an IFrame in it, you get a warning.  This may be only once per session.
- You can use `HTML('Hello, <b>world</b>')` at top level of cell and its return value will render.  Within a function, use `display(HTML(...))` as is done above.  This also allows you to mix `display` and `print` calls freely.
- Oddly, IFrames are indented slightly more than inline HTML.

Answer (score 3):

to do this in a loop, you can do:

```
display(HTML("".join([f"<a href='{url}'>{url}</a></br>" for url in urls])))
```

This essentially creates the html text in a loop, and then uses the display(HTML())  construct to display the whole string as HTML