# Download data from a jupyter server

Tags: python, download, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using ipython notebook by connecting to a server
I don't know how to download a thing (data frame, .csv file,... for example) programatically to my local computer. Because I can't specific declare the path like C://user//... It will be downloaded to their machine not mine

Answer (score 24):

Run this in separate cell in one of the notebooks:

```
!tar cvfz zipname.tar.gz *
```

To cover more folders up the tree, write ../ before the * for every step up the directory.

```
tar cvfz zipname.tar.gz ../../*
```

The file zipname.tar.gz will be saved in the same folder as your notebook.

Also if files size is too large execute the following in same notebook block

```
!split -b 200m allfiles.tar.gz allfiles.tar.gz.part
```

Alternatively you can use this extension https://github.com/data-8/nbzip

Comment: this answer is a treasure

Comment: I wish you also mention that by using `cat`, one can stitch the parts back together.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Jupyter notebook, you can go to the "File" tab on the top left part of the notebook and click "Open". It shows you the content of the current directory. You can select your data file with different format (CSV, text, etc) and then you can download it in your local computer.

[Open tab in Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H0DO.png)

[image]

[Download your desired file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX179.png)

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36328021/2641825),
the following function will export a pandas data frame to a csv file and it will provide you with a link to download the csv file in your browser:

```
def csv_download_link(df, csv_file_name, delete_prompt=True):
    """Display a download link to load a data frame as csv from within a Jupyter notebook"""
    df.to_csv(csv_file_name, index=False)
    from IPython.display import FileLink
    display(FileLink(csv_file_name))
    if delete_prompt:
        a = input('Press enter to delete the file after you have downloaded it.')
        import os
        os.remove(csv_file_name)
```

To get a link to a csv file, enter or import the above function and use the code below in a jupyter notebook cell :

```
csv_download_link(df, 'df.csv')
```

By default the argument `delete_prompt=True` makes sure that once you have downloaded the csv file, it gets deleted so the file doesn't pollute the git repository where you naturally archive your notebooks (converted in markdown format with [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for meaningful diffs).

Comment: I have come across a similar situation to this post and found your answer to be helpful. I work on JupyterLab and the csv files would only automatically download if they are opened in a new browser window. I can press Shift+right clink on the downloadable csv link that is created through  `def csv_download_link` to open the csv file in another browser. However, there are several csv files that I need to download in this way. So is there anyway to set these csv files to be opened in new browser windows automatically so that this would download the csv files to my local machine

Comment: @sam_rox The little function in my answer is just a quick hack in case there is not other way. If you have several files, it's better to write those data frames to some directory accessible from outside. For example if the notebook is running on a cluster, ask where is a shared drive accessible through owncloud. If the notebook is running on google collab, you could write the files to Google drive. There are many other places to store those files, check the documentation of the infrastructure where your notebook is running.

Answer (score 7):

The download option did not appear for me.

The solution was to open the file (which could not be correctly read as it was a binary file), and to download it from the notebook's notepad.

Answer (score 1):

You can also download the files directly from the Jupyter dashboard. To open it, either click on the Jupyter icon in the top left corner, or alternatively select <kbd>Open...</kbd> from the <kbd>File</kbd> menu:

[image: Open Jupyter dashboard]

After the dashboard has opened, select the file you want to download by checking the check box to the left of it. A <kbd>Download</kbd> button will appear in the actions bar above:

[image: Select and download file]