# Apache Zeppelin: Save DataFrame from notebook into CSV to local drive via browser

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, download, export-to-csv, apache-zeppelin

My Zeppelin installation (version - 0.9.0-preview1) is on a server. I have a Spark data frame which I converted to a Pandas dataframe assuming it would be an easy 'df.to_csv()'. I do realize that when I plot the dataframe as a SQL table using %sql, there is an option for downloading csv on the top right of the Helium ribbon. That only works if the number of rows in the data is less than 'zeppelin.spark.maxResult'. I increased the value for 'zeppelin.spark.maxResult' to 25,000 but that makes the browser slow and the application crashes on me. So I rolled it down to 10,000. We need just 10,000 rows to be plotted but if needed we want the capability of downloading the entire dataframe locally rather than just having a truncated dataset (equal to 'zeppelin.spark.maxResult' rows).

After searching, I came across a python function as follows from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893930/download-csv-from-an-ipython-notebook/36328021#36328021):

```
import base64
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML

def create_download_link( df, title = "Download CSV file", filename = "data.csv"):
    csv = df.to_csv()
    b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode())
    payload = b64.decode()
    html = '<a download="{filename}" href="data:text/csv;base64,{payload}" target="_blank">{title}</a>'
    html = html.format(payload=payload,title=title,filename=filename)
    return HTML(html)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['Col 1', 'Col 2'])
create_download_link(df)
```

But I get `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>` in the result.

I even tried to tweak this code and instead of the `return HTML(html)` I changed that to a `display(HTML(html))` after looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698448/how-to-embed-html-into-ipython-output) which gave me the same outcome

Another solution as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627247/download-data-from-a-jupyter-server) for Jupyter notebooks. I tried part of the suggested code:

```
def csv_download_link(df, csv_file_name):
    """Display a download link to load a data frame as csv from within a Jupyter notebook"""
    df.to_csv(csv_file_name, index=False)
    from IPython.display import FileLink
    display(FileLink(csv_file_name))

csv_download_link(df, 'df.csv')
```

gave me just a path to where the CSV is saved on the server `/folder/folder/df.csv`.

Now I have to figure out how to get the data from `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>` OR how do I create a URL that lets me download the file from the server at location `/folder/folder/df.csv`. The way Zeppelin's routing system is setup, even if I save it in the notebook folder within Zeppelin (where all notebooks reside), I still cannot access the file using `http://server.com/#/notebook/df.csv` OR `http://server.com/notebook/df.csv` inspite of the CSV file residing within the directory. As far as I understand this may be a security measure.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of zeppelin do you use?

Comment: I am using the latest version - 0.9.0-preview1

Comment: In zeppelin 0.9.0, the first solution works (if you use the `%python`interpreter).