# Python download files from Anaconda Notebook Automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

How to write python code to automate the process of downloading csv from Anaconda Notebook, below is my manual step to download it.

[image]

I saw similar question to download csv from ipython notebook,
[Download CSV from an iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893930/download-csv-from-an-ipython-notebook)
but, I don't know how to modify its code to make it works for Anaconda notebook?