# How to use Dashboard API from python plotly offline?

Tags: python, charts, offline, plotly, dashboard

I'm interessted in using plotly offline for analytical charts. This works fine for single charts, but I would like to fill a dashboard with different types of charts using the Dashboard API from plotly.
Is there any way to use it offline generating an HTML file?

Thanks a lot, 
Erik J

Comment: Hi Erik, I was wondering if you already have an answer on  your question as I am trying to do the same. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more work than you were looking for but you can create html divs using the method [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683147/getting-script-and-div-tags-from-plotly-using-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) and combine with a templating engine such as [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) to create an HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of using python plotly graphs offline:

1) Write import statements

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly as plotly
import plotly.express as px
```

2) write your plotly graph code e.g.

```
data = px.data.gapminder()

data_canada = data[data.country == 'Canada']
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop',
             hover_data=['lifeExp', 'gdpPercap'], color='lifeExp',
             labels={'pop':'population of Canada'}, height=400)
```

3) name your figure (provide reader-friendly name :) )

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename= output_filename + ".html")
```

4) Well-done! Please add comments, if you like my answer!