# Plotly graph shows up blank in a HTML page

Tags: python, html, plotly

I'm attempting to embed a graph into a HTML page using Python Plotly and Pandas, in Linux. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38032952/1907765) from user @Fermin Silva, which suggests using `plotly.offline.plot` to convert a plotly graph into a  object. This can then be embedded directly in a HTML.

So here's what I tried:

```
  1 import pandas as pd
  2 import plotly.graph_objs as go
  3 from plotly import tools
  4 import plotly
  5 import plotly.express as px
  6 
  7 data = {'Weekday': ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
  8         'Val': [4, 5, 9, 14, 26, 6, 14]}
  9 
 10 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 11 
 12 fig1 = px.line(df, x='Weekday', y='Val')
 13 div = plotly.offline.plot(fig1, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')  
 14 
 15 title = 'Example graph'
 16 
 17 html = '<html><head><title>{0}</title></head><body>{1}</body></html>'.format(title, div)
 18  
 19 with open('test3.html', 'w') as fw:
 20     fw.write(html)
```

When I run this script, it executes fully and creates the `test3.html` file, with the following contents:

```
<html>
      <head>
            <title>Example graph</title>
      </head>
      <body>
            <div>
        
        
            <div id="0e557daa-24ae-4b6f-865a-dbc84f6ede5c" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                
                    window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};
                    
                if (document.getElementById("0e557daa-24ae-4b6f-865a-dbc84f6ede5c")) {
                    Plotly.newPlot(
                        '0e557daa-24ae-4b6f-865a-dbc84f6ede5c',
                        [{"hoverlabel": {"namelength": 0}, "hovertemplate": "Weekday=%{x}<br>Val=%{y}", "legendgroup": "", "line": {"color": "#636efa", "dash": "solid"}, "mode": "lines", "name": "", "showlegend": false, "type": "scatter", "x": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"], "xaxis": "x", "y": [4, 5, 9, 14, 26, 6, 14], "yaxis": "y"}],
                        {"height": 600, "legend": {"tracegroupgap": 0}, "margin": {"t": 60}, "template": {"data": {"bar": [{"error_x": {"color": "#2a3f5f"}, "error_y": {"color": "#2a3f5f"}, "marker": {"line": {"color": "#E5ECF6", "width": 0.5}}, "type": "bar"}], "barpolar": [{"marker": {"line": {"color": "#E5ECF6", "width": 0.5}}, "type": "barpolar"}], "carpet": [{"aaxis": {"endlinecolor": "#2a3f5f", "gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "minorgridcolor": "white", "startlinecolor": "#2a3f5f"}, "baxis": {"endlinecolor": "#2a3f5f", "gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "minorgridcolor": "white", "startlinecolor": "#2a3f5f"}, "type": "carpet"}], "choropleth": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "type": "choropleth"}], "contour": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "contour"}], "contourcarpet": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "type": "contourcarpet"}], "heatmap": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "heatmap"}], "heatmapgl": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "heatmapgl"}], "histogram": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "histogram"}], "histogram2d": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "histogram2d"}], "histogram2dcontour": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "histogram2dcontour"}], "mesh3d": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "type": "mesh3d"}], "parcoords": [{"line": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "parcoords"}], "scatter": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scatter"}], "scatter3d": [{"line": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scatter3d"}], "scattercarpet": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scattercarpet"}], "scattergeo": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scattergeo"}], "scattergl": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scattergl"}], "scattermapbox": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scattermapbox"}], "scatterpolar": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scatterpolar"}], "scatterpolargl": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scatterpolargl"}], "scatterternary": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scatterternary"}], "surface": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "surface"}], "table": [{"cells": {"fill": {"color": "#EBF0F8"}, "line": {"color": "white"}}, "header": {"fill": {"color": "#C8D4E3"}, "line": {"color": "white"}}, "type": "table"}]}, "layout": {"annotationdefaults": {"arrowcolor": "#2a3f5f", "arrowhead": 0, "arrowwidth": 1}, "colorscale": {"diverging": [[0, "#8e0152"], [0.1, "#c51b7d"], [0.2, "#de77ae"], [0.3, "#f1b6da"], [0.4, "#fde0ef"], [0.5, "#f7f7f7"], [0.6, "#e6f5d0"], [0.7, "#b8e186"], [0.8, "#7fbc41"], [0.9, "#4d9221"], [1, "#276419"]], "sequential": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "sequentialminus": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]]}, "colorway": ["#636efa", "#EF553B", "#00cc96", "#ab63fa", "#FFA15A", "#19d3f3", "#FF6692", "#B6E880", "#FF97FF", "#FECB52"], "font": {"color": "#2a3f5f"}, "geo": {"bgcolor": "white", "lakecolor": "white", "landcolor": "#E5ECF6", "showlakes": true, "showland": true, "subunitcolor": "white"}, "hoverlabel": {"align": "left"}, "hovermode": "closest", "mapbox": {"style": "light"}, "paper_bgcolor": "white", "plot_bgcolor": "#E5ECF6", "polar": {"angularaxis": {"gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": ""}, "bgcolor": "#E5ECF6", "radialaxis": {"gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": ""}}, "scene": {"xaxis": {"backgroundcolor": "#E5ECF6", "gridcolor": "white", "gridwidth": 2, "linecolor": "white", "showbackground": true, "ticks": "", "zerolinecolor": "white"}, "yaxis": {"backgroundcolor": "#E5ECF6", "gridcolor": "white", "gridwidth": 2, "linecolor": "white", "showbackground": true, "ticks": "", "zerolinecolor": "white"}, "zaxis": {"backgroundcolor": "#E5ECF6", "gridcolor": "white", "gridwidth": 2, "linecolor": "white", "showbackground": true, "ticks": "", "zerolinecolor": "white"}}, "shapedefaults": {"line": {"color": "#2a3f5f"}}, "ternary": {"aaxis": {"gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": ""}, "baxis": {"gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": ""}, "bgcolor": "#E5ECF6", "caxis": {"gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": ""}}, "title": {"x": 0.05}, "xaxis": {"automargin": true, "gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": "", "zerolinecolor": "white", "zerolinewidth": 2}, "yaxis": {"automargin": true, "gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": "", "zerolinecolor": "white", "zerolinewidth": 2}}}, "xaxis": {"anchor": "y", "domain": [0.0, 0.98], "title": {"text": "Weekday"}}, "yaxis": {"anchor": "x", "domain": [0.0, 1.0], "title": {"text": "Val"}}},
                        {"responsive": true}
                    )
                };
                
            </script>
            </div>
       </body>
</html>
```

I try running this in Firefox using `firefox test3.html`, and no graph appears. I know that the  block is there, because it appears when I "Inspect element". But it's not rendering a Plotly graph:

[image]

I've tried opening the file in Chrome in Windows, and it's the same result.

In Fermin Silva's answer, they mentioned

> Remember that you'll need to include the plotly js file for all these
> charts to work.
>
> You could include
>
> `<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>`
>
> just before putting the div you got. If you put this js at the bottom of
> the page, the charts won't work.

Honestly, I don't really understand this - I don't know what is meant by the plotly js file, nor whether this applies to my setup. Nonetheless, I tried inserting this snippet before the outer  tag in my HTML file, and then I tried inserting it before the inner  tag, like so:

Attempt 1:

```
  1 <html><head><title>Example graph</title></head><body>    
  2  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>                   
  3         <div>
  4 
  5 
  6             <div id="0e557daa-24ae-4b6f-865a-dbc84f6ede5c" class="plotly-gra    ph-div" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>
```

Attempt 2:

```
  1 <html><head><title>Example graph</title></head><body>                       
  2         <div>
  3  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  4 
  5 
  6             <div id="0e557daa-24ae-4b6f-865a-dbc84f6ede5c" class="plotly-gra    ph-div" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>
```

And the graph still doesn't display.

I would appreciate anyone taking the time to explain what I'm doing wrong, and how I can correctly output a Plotly graph into a HTML file, so that it displays on a local webpage.

**EDIT:** So, a temporary workaround that I've found is to use `fig1.write_html(filename, auto_open=False)` to create a whole HTML file, then load that HTML file into BeautifulSoup and insert HTML as appropriate. I don't like it, because it means I'm effectively building a page around a graph, rather than the reverse, but it at least achieves my aim of getting a graph on a webpage.

If anyone knows how to fix the `div` insert, that would be great.

Comment: I don't see `Plotly` defined in the generated JavaScript.  Is it loaded somewhere on the page?  I see it in your 2nd attempt but it would be better to put it in the `<head>`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this to be honest. Where would you expect Plotly to be mentioned in the JavaScript?

Comment: It's being defined in the script that you're loading in the 2nd attempt from the CDN but you should move that `<script src="..."></script>` block to be in the `<head>` (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407962/when-to-use-the-script-tag-in-the-head-and-body-section-of-a-html-page/38408000))

Comment: So I've tried moving the script portion to the head as you suggest, but it's still not displaying the graph unfortunately. I'm not sure why it works when I use `write_html`, but not when I just grab a `div` and put it into a html file myself.

Comment: Okay that's interesting. I've just realised that it works in Chrome and Internet Explorer on Windows, but not in Firefox on Linux. I'm running Linux in a VM on Windows.

Comment: This parameter in your Python code: `include_plotlyjs=False` if set to `True` would likely prevent you from needing to use the CDN script at all

Comment: Ah! That worked! It's working both in Windows and in the Linux VM. Thanks :)

Comment: in your attempts, besides adding the `<div id="0e557daa-24ae-4b6f-865a-dbc84f6ede5c"`, are you also adding the rest of the javascript that the plotly div generates? You should be editing the line `html = '<html><head><title>{0}</title></head><body>{1}</body></html>'.format(title, div)` to add the plotly javascript inside that head

Comment: @FerminSilva, I'm not too sure what you mean by this. Using the code from your answer, I've added everything which is fed into the `div` variable in the line `div = plotly.offline.plot(fig1, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')`, into the HTML file. I've tried setting include_plotlyjs to True as Alex W suggested, and that does work, although it leads to a very verbose and lengthy HTML file. I haven't managed to make it work when include_plotlyjs is False.

Comment: Did you try something like this? `html = '<html><head><title>{0}</title><script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head><body>{1}</body></html>'.format(title, div)`

Comment: So I tried this again, and for some reason now it works when I change the div line to `div = plotly.offline.plot(fig1, include_plotlyjs="cdn", output_type='div')`. Before, it was outputting a blank graph. Maybe I forgot the double quotes? Either way, my problem appears to be solved!

Comment: ...Okay, I tried this again the next day, and now it doesn't work again, even with the code unchanged. I tried creating a new file and inserting a basic graph into a different HTML page. It now only works in Windows Chrome, not Linux Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use Graph Objects.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import cufflinks as cf
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px

import plotly.graph_objects as go

scoresByTeamId = {1: [100, 110, 115, 95, 112, 120, 110, 99], 2: [115, 99, 75, 111, 120, 77, 80, 110], 3: [100, 105, 102, 115, 99, 99, 100, 134]}
teamNamesByTeamId = {1: "John", 2: "Pete", 3: "Edgar"}
df_scores = pd.DataFrame(data=scoresByTeamId)

fig = go.Figure()

for team in scoresByTeamId:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                            y=scoresByTeamId[team],
                            name=teamNamesByTeamId[team],
                            mode="lines+markers"))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(title="Week",
                tickvals=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),
    yaxis=dict(title="Points Scored"),
    title="PPG by Week"
)

fig.show() # this is just to see it in browser in case you want to, it isn't necessary.
html = fig.to_html(full_html=True, include_plotlyjs=True)
print(html)

# save html file
filePath="C:\\myFilePath\\myHtmlFile.html"
with open(filePath, "w") as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
from

```
include_plotlyjs=False
```

to

```
include_plotlyjs=True
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> html_div = fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs= False )

to get a html div. You must iclude plotlyjs somewhere but