# Python Plotly - Offline chart embed into HTML (Not working)

Tags: python, html, plotly

I have built a chart which I want to embed into an HTML file. If I use `plotly` online, it works as intended. However, if I use OFFLINE the offline chart works (i.e. It opens up a separate HTML chart with it in it), but it is not embedding into the HTML (nick.html) i.e. the `iframe` is empty.

This is my code:

```
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='*****', api_key='*****')
aPlot = plotly.offline.plot(fig, config={"displayModeBar": False}, show_link=False,
                             filename='pandas-continuous-error-bars.html')

html_string = '''
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>body{ margin:0 100; background:whitesmoke; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Monthly Report</h1>

        <!-- *** Section 1 *** --->
        <h2></h2>
        <iframe width="1000" height="550" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" \
src="''' + aPlot + '''.embed?width=800&height=550"></iframe>
        <p> (Insights).</p>


    </body>
</html>'''

f = open("C:/Users/nicholas\Desktop/nick.html",'w')
f.write(html_string)
f.close()
```

Anyone know why it isn't embedding and how to fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`aPlot` is the filename of your Plotly file.

In your `iframe` you add `.embed?width=800&height=550` to the filename which results in a filename which does not exist.

When you remove this string, i.e. `src="''' + aPlot + '''"`, it should work.

Instead of embedding the whole HTML file you can also use the approach suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38032952/2776376) which generates a smaller HTML file, i.e. generate a `div` with all the relevant information and include `plotly.js` in your header.

```
import plotly

fig = {'data': [{'x': [1,2,3],
                  'y': [2,5,3],
                  'type': 'bar'}],
      'layout': {'width': 800,
                 'height': 550}}

aPlot = plotly.offline.plot(fig, 
                            config={"displayModeBar": False}, 
                            show_link=False, 
                            include_plotlyjs=False, 
                            output_type='div')

html_string = '''
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <style>body{ margin:0 100; background:whitesmoke; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Monthly Report</h1>
      ''' + aPlot + '''
    </body>
</html>'''

with open("nick.html", 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_string)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. I'm just boarding a plane so can't check if it works but the logic looks good and I understand, so thank you very much :)

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica: As far as I know the Stackoverflow page doesn't support running Python code, only Javascript. So I guess, no, it won't run on Stackoverflow.