# How do I save an interactive plotly chart as a local file in R?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, plotly

I've created an interactive plotly chart with plotly() in R and I'd like to save it as a file.

I'm okay with it being in any format, whether that's js or html or something else. I want to keep the interactivity.

This is my code

```
gg <-
   iris %>%
   ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.length)) +
   geom_col(fill = "green")

ggplotly(gg)
```

I read on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262748/python-save-plotly-plot-to-local-file-and-insert-into-html) that you can do `plotly.offline.plot(data, filename='file.html')` in the Python implementation for Plotly. My goal is to upload the plotly chart to a Notion document using the "upload file" functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `saveWidget()` from `htmlwidgets` package:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)
#Plot
gg <-
  iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_col(fill = "green")
#Export
saveWidget(ggplotly(gg), file = "myplot.html")
```