# how to display a python string as HTML in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In IPython notebook, I used to be able to display a python string that contains html as actual html, by using the `HTML` function from IPython's display module.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
```

In jupyter notebook the display module no longer exists. Does anyone know where I can find the HTML function?

I use Jupyter notebook 4.1, IPython 4.0.2 and Python 3.5.1 64 bit

Comment: It's still there in `IPython.display`. The Python interfaces that your code in the notebook uses is part of *IPython*. Jupyter is the language-independent pieces, like the notebook UI and document format.

Comment: What the heck! I am affraid I made an embarrassing typo when trying this! Thanks very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed HTML into iPython output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698448/how-to-embed-html-into-ipython-output)

Answer (score 31):

Use the function `display`

```
def bar():
    from IPython.display import display, HTML
    chart = HTML('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>')
    # or chart = charts.plot(...)
    display(chart)

bar()
```

source: http://suanfazu.com/t/jupyter-highcharts/13438/2