# Printing f-strings in color in Jupyter with escape characters in the mix

Tags: python, string, jupyter-notebook, escaping, ipython

I know that similar questions were asked before, but I couldn't find anything exactly on point. 
Say I have this list:

```
tags = ['<div>','<body>','<h1>']
```

I can easily use f-strings here:

```
for tag in tags:
   print(f'this is your tag: {tag}')
```

Output:

```
this is your tag: <div>
this is your tag: <body>
this is your tag: <h1>
```

So far so good. But I am really trying to do, is get the same output but with the tag names printed in, for example, red. And this is where I run into problems with the brackets. If I use:

```
from IPython.display import HTML as html_print

for tag in tags:
     html_print(f'this is your tag: {tag}')
```

nothing prints out - even if I remove the tags.

I tried:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
```

And then first:

```
for tag in tags:
   display(f'this is your tag: {tag}')
```

That works like a regular `print`.

If, however, I try:

```
for tag in tags:    
   display(Markdown((f'this is your tag: {tag}')))
```

The output is:

```
this is your tag:
this is your tag:
this is your tag:
```

My understanding is that I need `Markdown` to print in color, but obviously the brackets are causing problems with the f-strings in `Markdown`, unlike the case with `print` and `display`. So how do I get around that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267578/how-to-display-a-python-string-as-html-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: @hpaulj - Nope, doesn't work with tags, I'm afraid.

Comment: What happens if you do `x=HTML(f...)` (or `Markdown`), and then `display(x)`.  And look at `x.data`.

Comment: @hpaulj - Tried these too - any combination I could think of; the moment you introduce HTML or Markdown - it's game over. What do you mean by `x.data`?

Comment: Strings like `'<div>'` have to be escaped to be displayed in html.  Otherwise they are interpreted as html markings.  `x = '<h1> a string </h1>'` defines an html header.  `x='a string <h1>'` is an incomplete html line.

Comment: @hpaulj - Yes, I thought about that, but it requires that I replace each occurrence of `<` in each list item with `&lt;` (and so for all other troublesome characters) before feeding it to `Markdown`. That works (and can be used as answer if all else fails), but I thought there was a simple solution in the IPython library.

Comment: `import html` and `html.escape(tag)`.

Comment: @hpaulj - You've got it! Now it works. Thanks! Do you want to turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @hpaulj (in the comments to the question) we now have a nice and simple answer - add `html.escape(tag)` to the code. The final lineup looks like this:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
import html

for tag in tags:    
    tag = html.escape(tag)
    display(Markdown((f'this is your tag: <text style=color:red>{tag}</text>')))
```

Output:

[image]

Simple and effective...