# R - how to embed HTML code into Jupyter notebook output?

Tags: python, html, r, styles, jupyter-notebook

How can I do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698448/how-to-embed-html-into-ipython-output) using R? Actually I want to set Jupyter notebook cells width to 100%. In python this code works perfectly:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML, display
HTML("<style>.container { width: 100%; }</style>")
```

Is there any equivalent in R?

Thank you!

Comment: Finally I edited `/anaconda/Lib/site-packages/notebook/static/style/style.min.css` to always "force" 100% width. I added `width: 100%;` to `#notebook-container`.

Comment: It looks like you solved the problem in a better way than using R. Thanks for this tip. You can probably create a custom css file that Jupyter will read in addition to the defaults. There are also notebook extensions that might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can display html code in R using the `display_html` function *e.g.*,

```
// for full width
IRdisplay::display_html('<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>')

// this does not work with most sites due to same-origin policy, but no problem with local files   
IRdisplay::display_html('<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width=1000, height=1000></iframe> ')
```

See: [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Answer (score 1):

### Embed html code and html table to IR Kernel jupyter

```
  library(IRdisplay)

  display_html("your html code")
```

**Some packages in R give tables in html format like "knitr", so if you want to put this tables in the notebook:**

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
options(knitr.table.format = "html") 
html_table= kable(dt) %>%
   kable_styling("striped") %>%
   add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2" = 2, "Group 3" = 2))

display_html(toString(html_table))
```