# Show output of .html file in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I can create an html file using this code:

```
with open(file_loc+'file.html', 'w') as html:
    html.write(s.set_table_attributes("border=1").render())
```

How can I show the output in Jupyter Notebooks without creating the file?

If I simply try to render it in Jupyter (shown below) then it shows the html code instead of displaying the desired output that I would see in my browser:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
s.set_table_attributes("border=1").render()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed HTML into iPython output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698448/how-to-embed-html-into-ipython-output)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to invoke IPython's `HTML` function:

```
 HTML(s.set_table_attributes("border=1").render())
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML(filename="profiling/z2pDecisionTreeProfiling.html")
```