# Python: Pretty Print in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, python-2.x, pretty-print

I am trying to pretty print a dict in Jupyter Notebook.

I am using the following:

```
import pprint
stuff = ['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
stuff.insert(0, stuff[:])
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(stuff)
```

However upon pressing shift+enter, no `[out]` cell appear (i.e. I can't see the pretty printed output)

[image]

Any idea why this is so/ what should I change in order to see the pretty printed output?

---

Edit: Actually this is a python 2.7 problem - it works fine in 3.x.
Have anyone tried it on python 2.7 and seen it work?

Comment: The same code works fine for me. I am using Python 3.6

Comment: @Ujjwal Oh I see - I am using 2.7... Do you have any idea what would be the coreect syntax in 2.7 ?

Comment: I tested your code on https://try.jupyter.org/ and it did show output.

Comment: you could try outputting html, as pretty as you wish:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698448/how-to-embed-html-into-ipython-output

Comment: @jimbasquiat Yes it works on 2.7

Comment: Also working here. Cannot reproduce

Answer (score 7):

Whatever you develop is correct. The only possible reason could be, Jupyter Notebook is unable to connect to the server. If you see connecting to Kernal/server like the image below in the toolbar, try to refresh the connection or reload the page.

[image]

I used the same code and I am able to see the output. check the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Python 3, in my case solved removing an AD block extension.. somehow it was blocking the AJAX request that set the output..

Answer (score 0):

The title is generic to more than dict in Jupyter, so i give a generic answer.

When printing, change this

```
print(longValue, nextValue)
```

to this (have to try with other values than 30)

```
space = (30-len(longValue)*" "
print(longValue,space,nextValue)
```

That will change this

[image]

Into this

[image]

Comment: Easier to let Python calculate the spaces for you with: `print("{:30s} {:s} ".format(longVal, nextVal))`