# How to view scraped text with formatting?

Tags: python, formatting, ipython

I'm in iPython notebook. I scraped a website and now my text formatting contains all of the hidden "\n" and so on...

Is there a way to see the output formatted with the newlines and everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698448/how-to-embed-html-into-ipython-output):

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(myHTML))
```