# Replicate jupyter HTML output using IPython and Spyder instead

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, spyder

The following snippet will produce the output below in Jupyter:

```
display(HTML('<h2>Hello, world!</h2>'))
```

[image]

Running the same snippet in an IPython console in Spyder only returns `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>` like this:

[image]

Is it possible to display the same output in an IPython console using Spyder?
I thought I would get somewhere with `from IPython.core.display import display, HTML` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698448/how-to-embed-html-into-ipython-output), but I may be missing the point completely.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a plugin for Spyder which integrates notebooks: [Spyder-Notebook](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook) (I have not used this). Pycharm also has an integration.

Answer (score 7):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The Spyder IPython console doesn't support html output, so the above code doesn't work on it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Just to clarify; do you mean the snippet I provided, or the suggestion from Igaud?

Comment: The suggestion from @lgaud is about `spyder-notebook`, a plugin that runs the Jupyter notebook inside Spyder.

Comment: Is there at least a simple way to catch the object and put it in a matplotlib.pyplot.figure ?

Comment: @Keith, if you're referring to having dedicated panel for Maptlotlib plots, that's already implemented and it'll be part of Spyder 4. You can look at a preview [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/6430).

Comment: I was hoping for something more generic. I am using Canopy. For example eli5.show_weights() produces a IPython.core.display.HTML object and I want it in a matplotlib figure. Would be happy to go through a png to get there

Comment: Well, this question is about Spyder and Html ouput, so you should ask another question.

Comment: I have been wondering why both Spyder and PyCharm still use (mainly) text console. Wouldn't it be possible to use Qt WebEngine to have all output displayed by _repr_html_() when available? This is with regular .py files, without Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative idea would be to store the output of the permutation feature importance into an html file and open it with the default browser. I got the idea from  [J Hudok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11799377/j-hudock) in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908239/how-can-i-display-a-ipython-core-display-html-object-in-spyder-ipython-console/63238457#63238457). The following is my working example

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import webbrowser

# Load iris data & convert to dataframe
iris_data = load_iris()
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'sepal length': iris_data.data[:,0],
    'sepal width': iris_data.data[:,1],
    'petal length': iris_data.data[:,2],
    'petal width': iris_data.data[:,3],
    'species': iris_data.target
})
X = data[['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width']]
y = data['species']

# Split train & test dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

# Initialize classifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=56, max_depth=8, random_state=1, verbose=1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Compute permutation feature importance
perm_importance = PermutationImportance(clf, random_state=0).fit(X_test, y_test)

# Store feature weights in an object
html_obj = eli5.show_weights(perm_importance, feature_names = X_test.columns.tolist())

# Write html object to a file (adjust file path; Windows path is used here)
with open('C:\\Tmp\\Desktop\iris-importance.htm','wb') as f:
    f.write(html_obj.data.encode("UTF-8"))

# Open the stored HTML file on the default browser
url = r'C:\\Tmp\\Desktop\iris-importance.htm'
webbrowser.open(url, new=2)
```