# Jupyter pandas.DataFrame output table format configuration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Where can I configure Jupyter to make a DataFrame object appear as a **full-bordered table** by default?

Now it looks like this:

[image]

I wish it could look like:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the following code to your notebook, which will apply to all cells in the current notebook regardless of what cell it's entered in:

```
%%HTML
<style type="text/css">
    table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
        border-style: solid;
    }
</style>
```

If you want it to apply to all notebooks, you can add a custom config/css file. Answers on how to do that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser).

You might also want to explore [jupyterthemes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) depending on how much other configuration you want to do.

Comment: I tried this solution, but seems what it did was to remove all the line numbers in []

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? I read your question as looking to get rid of the In[] and Out[]. Rereading, are you just looking to add an outer border to dataframes in the output?

Comment: Sorry about that, edited question. Basically, I want full borders around all table cells.

Comment: Gotcha. See the updated answer. Basically the answer to any question like this is if you want to do it from the jupyter notebook side is going to be to use CSS. Pandas also has pd.set_option('html.border', 1) and pd.options... but not sure how to get either of those to work.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I also followed the instructions in the first link you provided (included at the bottom of my comment). It also works. Note: no need to restart Jupyter everytime you change the css file, just need to restart the notebook you are running. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser

Comment: awesome! with `border: 1px solid lightgray;` tables look perfect!

Comment: Use this logic to make the **font smaller** and it's SO much easier to read now.  Thanks!

Comment: I would like to apply this to only one output and not through the entire notebook. Is this possible?

Comment: Instead of using the %%HTML cell magic, you can use display/HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35760941/7619676