# Python Jupyter Notebook print dataframe borders

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I'm probably have a simple question but I can't seem to find a solution online.
If I create a dataframe "df" in a Jupyter notebook and then I print it out using print(), the table displayed in my broswer does not show any borders at all.
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2), columns=["a","b"])
print(df)
```

This will show a table with no border.
I read [Jupyter pandas.DataFrame output table format configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798508/jupyter-pandas-dataframe-output-table-format-configuration) 
but that seems to help if I simply type

```
df.head()
```

not the output of the print() function.
Does somebody have any suggestions?
Many thanks

Comment: `print()` calls `__str__()` (or `__repr__()`) on the object so will turn it into a string. `df.head()` is equivalent to `from IPython.display import display; 
display(df.head())`. You can just type `df` and it will do the same thing for the whole table.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

@Angel, you can add this script in any cell to introduce table borders. Use `df` instead of `print(df)`

```
%%HTML
<style type="text/css">
table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
    border: 1px  black solid !important;
  color: black !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! May I ask where I could read more about that code in case I want to learn? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Angelo.. yes. There are alot of information online. Let me explain to you. What you have is actually calling in python notebook is the inline 'HTML' and adjusting the css part of datatable td/th. You can learn alot of css from here 1. https://www.w3schools.com/css/  and here 2.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/How_CSS_works

Comment: Nice, but how do you apply this to only one output and not all the dataframes? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of print(df) you use:

```
from IPython.display import display
display(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @MEdwin is perfect, just need to close the *style* tag, otherwise the broken HTML results in 'eated up' output of several output cells, which follows the HTML code.

```
%%HTML
<style type="text/css">
table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
    border: 1px  black solid !important;
  color: black !important;
}
</style>
```