# How to visually format a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

When I print my dataframe, it appears with default style.
[image: Dataframe with styling]

How can I format of style it to look like this:
[image: Dataframe without styling]

Comment: May i ask you why that is important to you? To your question: What IDE do you use?

Comment: @FlorianH maybe he wants a screenshot to put on a blog or school report.

Comment: Seems like what you want can be achieved with IPython console configuration (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888173/python-jupyter-notebook-print-dataframe-borders) or probably may be achieved with pandas styling (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html).

Comment: @Aditya I think OP wants to revert the "new" style to the "old" one. See the original question.

Comment: @JanTrienes how do I access the edit history?

Comment: Press ["edited X mins ago"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52759094/revisions).

Comment: Oh yes you were right. Thanks. Will edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default styling has been changed in Jupyter PR [#1776](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/1776).

If you want to return to the old styling, you can redefine the CSS within your Jupyter notebook or adjust the [`custom.css`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156248/how-do-i-set-custom-css-for-my-ipython-ihaskell-jupyter-notebook).

The following looks close to the old style.

```
%%html
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```