# Add table borders in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

HERE is the code:

```
customers = {'CustomerID': [10, 11],
         'Name': ['Mike', 'Marcia'],
         'Address': ['Address for Mike','Address for Marcia']}
customers = pd.DataFrame(customers)
customers
```

What I get  in my Jupyter notebook is below :

```
  CustomerID      Name           Address

0         10      Mike  Address for Mike

1         11    Marcia  Address for Marcia
```

What I want is that it can print the tables with solid borders.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

it works for me if you copy the following code into any cell in the current jupyter notebook

```
%%HTML
<style type="text/css">
table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
    border-style: solid;
}
```

more details, please follow the link

[Jupyter pandas.DataFrame output table format configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798508/jupyter-pandas-dataframe-output-table-format-configuration)