# how to install HTML on anaconda Prompt.Is it possible to write HTML code on jupyter notebook

Tags: html, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

how to install HTML on anaconda Prompt.Is it possible to write HTML code on jupyter notebook.
Is there is any command to install html on anaconda Prompt.

Comment: You can write Markdown in Jupyter Notebook. Select a cell and press `Esc + M` to enable markdown formatting in that particular cell. You can refer to [https://devhints.io/markdown](https://devhints.io/markdown) for markdown syntax.

Comment: i asked command to install HTML on anaconda @SoumikRakshit

Comment: HTML is not a piece of software that you can install. If you need formatted text on a Jupyter Notebook, Markdown is the easiest way to do so. However, you can write HTML inside a Markdown-enabled cell.

Comment: HTML is a language.Like we can write codes in python and R on jupyter notebook,Can we write HTML codes in html on jupyter notebook,@SoumikRakshit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed HTML into iPython output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698448/how-to-embed-html-into-ipython-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
HTML('[link](http://example.com)')

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use HTML via `ipython`, you can use the following code:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'))
```