# No html webpage shown from tensoflow data validation visualize_statistics() when run from databricks notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, ipython, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use tensorflow (2.2) data validation (TFDV version: 0.22.2) to visualize data on databricks GPU cluster.

From databricks notebook, I am running the code at :
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/docs/tutorials/data_validation/tfdv_basic.ipynb

But, when I run

```
  tfdv.visualize_statistics(train_stats)
```

I got:

```
 <IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

no html webpage shown.

I have tried to update matlibplot but it does not work.

I have also tried https://python-forum.io/Thread-How-to-display-IPython-core-display-HTML-object
and [How to embed HTML into IPython output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698448/how-to-embed-html-into-ipython-output)

but still no html shown.

Could anybody help me about this ?

thanks

**UPDATE**

I have tried :

```
html = tfdv.visualize_statistics(train_stats).data
```

got:

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 <command-2488671> in <module>
```

----> 1 html = tfdv.visualize_statistics(train_stats).data

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: Hi @user3448011, Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by importing the [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/blob/master/tensorflow_data_validation/utils/display_util.py#L414) that generates the HTML objects and calling those instead of the visualize functions. Then, visualize those functions with the DataBricks displayHTML function.

```
from tensorflow_data_validation.utils.display_util import get_statistics_html
displayHTML(get_statistics_html(train_stats))
```

The issue is that the tfdv utility notebook imports Ipython display functionality, and overrides the DataBricks display function with the Ipython display function inside visualize functions.

```
try:
  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
  from IPython.display import display
  from IPython.display import HTML
except ImportError as e:
```

The display_anomalies function has a similar issue and can be solved by importing the get_anomalies_dataframe function directly and displaying the resulting pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly in a jupyter notebook, which is required to visualize this  <IPython.core.display.HTML object>

You can get the HTML code with:

```
html = tfdv.visualize_statistics(train_stats).data
```

Comment: I have tried "html = tfdv.visualize_statistics(train_stats).data", but got error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to display the statistics with a workaround:

I copy-pasted to my databricks notebook most of the code in [this page](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/blob/v1.4.0/tensorflow_data_validation/utils/display_util.py) and modified [this function](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/blob/v1.4.0/tensorflow_data_validation/utils/display_util.py#L390) so that instead of displaying the html it returned it. Like this:

```
def visualize_statistics(
    lhs_statistics: statistics_pb2.DatasetFeatureStatisticsList,
    rhs_statistics: Optional[
        statistics_pb2.DatasetFeatureStatisticsList] = None,
    lhs_name: Text = 'lhs_statistics',
    rhs_name: Text = 'rhs_statistics',
    allowlist_features: Optional[List[types.FeaturePath]] = None,
    denylist_features: Optional[List[types.FeaturePath]] = None) -> None:
  """Visualize the input statistics using Facets.
  Args:
    lhs_statistics: A DatasetFeatureStatisticsList protocol buffer.
    rhs_statistics: An optional DatasetFeatureStatisticsList protocol buffer to
      compare with lhs_statistics.
    lhs_name: Name of the lhs_statistics dataset.
    rhs_name: Name of the rhs_statistics dataset.
    allowlist_features: Set of features to be visualized.
    denylist_features: Set of features to ignore for visualization.
  Raises:
    TypeError: If the input argument is not of the expected type.
    ValueError: If the input statistics protos does not have only one dataset.
  """
  assert (not allowlist_features or not denylist_features), (
      'Only specify one of allowlist_features and denylist_features.')
  html = get_statistics_html(lhs_statistics, rhs_statistics, lhs_name, rhs_name,
                             allowlist_features, denylist_features)
  return html
```

After that you can simply do:

```
displayHTML(visualize_statistics(train_stats))
```

I know, it's not ideal, but it worked.