# How do I turn a link to an image in a Python DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the links in the column but I am trying to convert them to images

```
thumbnails = []
for index,row in pdr.iterrows():
    s = row['videoId']
    thumbnail_url = f"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{s}/maxresdefault.jpg"
    thumbnails.append(thumbnail_url)
pdr['thumbnail'] = thumbnails
```

Output:
[image: Code Output]

This is the output. I am trying to fill the 'thumbnail' column with images as opposed to linked text.

Comment: While, if you want image data, you can download it and read and parse it into a matrix, and save this matrix as the content of this cell.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/38092/87159

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
thumbnails = []
for index,row in pdr.iterrows():
    s = row['videoId']
    thumbnail_url = f"<img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{s}/maxresdefault.jpg' width='100px'>"
    thumbnails.append(thumbnail_url)
pdr['thumbnail'] = thumbnails
```

We have created the DataFrame, now we have to show it:

```
from IPython.display import Image, HTML

HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

This will show you the DataFrame with real image rather then only link.

Learn more from here:

- [HTML  tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)
- [df.to_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html#pandas-dataframe-to-html)
- [IPython.display.HTML()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698448/how-to-embed-html-into-ipython-output)

Answer (score 0):

```
from IPython.display import Image


Image(url= "http://my_site.com/my_picture.jpg")
```