# Can I get html string from IPython.display.Markdown?

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I want to get html from markdown on Jupyter Notebook.

like this.

```
from IPython import display
display.Code("import this")._repr_html_()
```

But I get:

> IPython.core.display.Markdown object has no attribute '_repr_html_'.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is (directly) possible; the Markdown -> HTML conversion for, say, `mdout = md("## string ..."); display(mdout)` seems to happen in JavaScript, in the `append_markdown` function, defined here:

- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/238828e/notebook/static/notebook/js/outputarea.js#L730

Of course, if someone can come up with a way, to do a JavaScript call from Jupyter Python cell to perform this conversion, and then get the results back in Python before doing the `display(...)`, then it would be possible `:)`

For more discussion, see:

- https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-obtain-html-string-from-markdown-as-jupyter-does-it/10589

---

EDIT: However, I just found a method to cheat through this (see also [IPython: Adding Javascript scripts to IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852885/ipython-adding-javascript-scripts-to-ipython-notebook/69029975#69029975)) - you don't get the HTML string directly back in Python, but you can send the markdown string from Python, and control the `display()` of the converted string; the trick is to write in a separate `<div>`, and have JavaScript store the result of the conversion there.

So you can put this in a code (Python) cell in Jupyter:

```py
def js_convert_md_html(instring_md):
    js_convert = """
        <div id="_my_special_div"></div>
        <script>
        //import * as markdown from "base/js/markdown"; //import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
        //define(['base/js/markdown'], function ttttest(markdown) {{ // Mismatched anonymous define() module: 
        //    console.log(markdown);
        //}});
        //const markdown = require('base/js/markdown'); // redeclaration of const markdown
        //console.log(markdown); // is there!
        function do_convert_md_html(instr) {{
            //return instr.toUpperCase();
            markdown.render(instr, {{
                        with_math: true,
                        clean_tables: true,
                        sanitize: true,
                    }}, function (err, html) {{
                        //console.log(html); //ok
                        $("#_my_special_div").html(html);
                    }});
        }}
        var myinputstring = '{0}';
        do_convert_md_html(myinputstring);
        </script>
    """.format(instring_md)
    return HTML(js_convert)

jsobj = js_convert_md_html("*hello* **world** $$x_2 = e^{x}$$")
display(jsobj)
```

This results with:

[image: md-converted]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using the markdown package to convert markdown to HTML and combining it with other HTML

> pip install markdown

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import markdown

#Convert markdown to html
html = markdown.markdown("""# Pandas and Plotly guide

Here we have [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [Plotly Express library](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) used in combination with:

* Ipyvuetify (ipywidgets Vuetify UI framework)
* Ipymonaco ( a text editor widget)


Available plot types:
""")

# copy some html from the plotly express website
html += """<ul>
<li><strong>Basics</strong>: <a href="https://www.plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/" target="_blank"><code>scatter</code></a>, <a href="https://www.plotly.com/python/line-charts/" target="_blank"><code>line</code></a>, <a href="https://www.plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/" target="_blank"><code>area</code></a>, <a href="https://www.plotly.com/python/bar-charts/" target="_blank"><code>bar</code></a>, <a href="https://www.plotly.com/python/funnel-charts/" target="_blank"><code>funnel</code></a>, <a href="https://plotly.comhttps://www.plotly.com/python/gantt/" target="_blank"><code>timeline</code></a></li>
</ul>"""

help_links = widgets.HTML(value = html)
help_links
```

[image]

Comment: The question clearly asks if this can be done in IPython. Not all environments allow users to add libraries at will.

Comment: @JosephMeadows although not directly answering the question, it did answer the opening statement in the main text. And it may be useful for folks looking for similar solutions.   Point taken though ... if I get more downvotes I'll remove.   (Also, I would say most Jupyter users can add Python libraries at will. )