# Print text into Jupyter notebook cell from %%html using Javascript

Tags: jquery, dom, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter notebook we may use some magic functions shortcuts like so:

```
%%javascript
element.text('Hi')
```

This outputs in the current cell as expected. (If I'm not mistaken `element` here stands for current cell in DOM of jupyter notebook).

> 'Hi'

**Question:** Is there a way to do the same with `%%html`?
 My naive attempt doesn't work.

```
%%html
<script>element.text('Hi');</script>
```

Notice that such construct works just fine.

```
%%html
<script>alert('Hi');</script>
```

I'm not that good with jQuery and notebook DOM structure, so some explanation will be welcome. I read a few similar questions, like [16852885](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852885/ipython-adding-javascript-scripts-to-ipython-notebook) but fail to find the relevant analog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the `element` variable is not directly available in an `%%html` cell. To have access to the `element` variable, you first need to create it. It should be the parent of the `<script>` tag in the `%%html` cell. An easy way to get the `<script>` tag is to give it an ID.

If you don't need jquery, you can do the following:

```
%%html
<script id="unique">
    var element = document.getElementById('unique').parentElement;
    element.innerHTML = "Hi";
</script>
```

If you want to use jquery, you should load it first:

```
%%html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script id="unique2">
    var element = $('#unique2').parent();
    element.text("Hi (jquery)")
</script>
```